# Android - Eclipse Fast View Not Dismissing LogCat with Escape

Tags: android, eclipse, escaping, logcat, dismiss

Can't seem to find anything on this except an Eclipse bug report in 2004 (which I assume has been fixed!).

While using Eclipse (Galileo), I like to keep the LogCat in a Fast View to keep my screen clean and full of code. But I often have to switch back and forth between the code and the LogCat while chasing bugs. I have a nice keystroke set up to display the Fast View, but  does not dismiss this particular Fast View (yes, it works on other Fast Views!).

Any advice? Moving the mouse and clicking on a piece of Eclipse that does not show the LogCat is the only way I know of dismissing this Fast View--and since I'm a keyboard programmer, this is not only a pain, but it really slows me down.

And now for 2000 words of information: Here's a pic of my normal coding screen:
[image]

And here's what it looks like with the LogCat:
[image]

Thanks,
-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I was also facing this issue. What I am doing right now is working with **LogCat(deprecated)**. Its working good try to use the deprecated one

Comment: Well, it's kind of a hack, but you're right: it works.  Any idea why the old, deprecated version works while the new one doesn't?

Comment: It seems to be something related to focusing of new LogCat window. The new LogCat window doesn't get focused when it is opened you have to click on it to get focus. After clicking the new LogCat window you can press escape to close it. While the other windows got focused when they are opened that's why they got closed right away after pressgin escape.